# How to Hid Default Dashboard and Chart after connect Database

Tags: charts, hide, dashboard

Is there any ways to delete multiple chart or dashboard in Superset ?
How to hide all default chart and dashboard after connect database ?
(I install with docker)

I got trouble with above problems and I'm deleting them one by one. Hope there is some better solutions